# adding a condition to a java code where user can only have 4 tries

Tags: java

So I have this code where the user enters a random number from 0 to 9 and has to guess the number but I want to limit the users trials to 4 once he guessed wrong 4 times the system stops and displays a message "you exceeded your allowed trials" this is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int nb,x;
    int count= 0;
    Scanner inp= new Scanner(System.in);
    nb= (int)(Math.random()*10);
    System.out.print("Guess the number between 0 and 9");
    x=inp.nextInt();

    while(x!= nb) {
        if(x>nb) System.out.println("Lesser");
        else if (x<nb) System.out.println("Bigger");
        System.out.println("Try another Number");
        x=inp.nextInt();
        count++;

    }

    System.out.println("Found!!");
    System.out.println("Number of Guesses:" +count);


    inp.close();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also used you `count` variable to keep track of attempts, once user ends with limit you can exit the program by breaking the `while` loop using `break` statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int nb,x;
    int count= 1;
    Scanner inp= new Scanner(System.in);
    nb= (int)(Math.random()*10);
    System.out.print(nb);
    System.out.print("Guess the number between 0 and 9:");
    x=inp.nextInt();

    while(x!= nb) {
        if (count <= 3){
        if(x>nb) System.out.println("Lesser");
        else if (x<nb) System.out.println("Bigger");
        System.out.println("Try another Number");
        x=inp.nextInt();
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("you exceeded your allowed trials");
            break;

        }
        count++;

    }

    System.out.println("Found!!");
    System.out.println("Number of Guesses:" +count);


    inp.close();

   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly , just made a few changes to my code by removing the number of guesses since i no longer need to specify the number since its by default 4

Answer (score 1):

```
    while(x!= nb) {
        if(x>nb) System.out.println("Lesser");
        else if (x<nb) System.out.println("Bigger");
        System.out.println("Try another Number");
        x=inp.nextInt();
        count++;
        if(count == 4) {
            if(x == nb) break; // Leave the while loop and print "Found" message
            System.out.println("You exceeded your allowed trials");
            return; // Skip the message after the while-loop.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your count variable to validate the quantity of the wrong answers and then us `System.exit(0)` method to finish the application.

Example:

```
if (count == 4 && x != nb) {
 System.out.println("you exceeded your allowed trials");
 //Terminate the application
 System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: @QuantumDeveloper you were right, I fixed the answer